# Fazer com que visualização google-charts bar inicie do zero

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Tenho um gráfico do google charts no sistema que pode ser que venha zerado, caso venha zerado preciso que inicie do 0, porém não estou conseguindo configurar, tentei usar `viewWindow.min` porém não funciona.

A [documentação](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options) não cita nada a respeito.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [
      "",
      "",
      {
        "role": "style"
      },
      {
        "role": "annotation"
      }
    ],
    [
      "A",
      0,
      "#64BBF6",
      "0 | R$ 0,00"
    ],
    [
      "B",
      0,
      "#2A8FD7",
      "0 | R$ 0,00"
    ],
    [
      "C",
      0,
      "#0862A2",
      "0 | R$ 0,00"
    ],
    [
      "D",
      0,
      "#64BBF6",
      "0 | R$ 0,00"
    ]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: '',
    chartArea: {
      width: '60%'
    },
    height: 100,
    hAxis: {
      title: '',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
      },
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: '',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
      },
    },
    legend: {
      position: "none"
    },
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        bold: true
      },
      alwaysOutside: true
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "none"
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

No exemplo acima ele inicia do -1, preciso fazer que comece do 0, mesmo quando não há dados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade seu gráfico já começa no **0**, ele só gera os negativos quando nenhum dos valores é maior que zero. Não sei dizer o por que isso ocorre, mas você pode contornar usando o `hAxis.ticks` para substituir essa geração automática.

Mudei as opções do seu **hAxis** adicionando ele:

```
hAxis: {
    title: '',
    ticks: [0,1,2,3],
    viewWindow: {
    min: 0,
}
```

**Veja funcionando no seu exemplo abaixo:**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [
      "",
      "",
      {
        "role": "style"
      },
      {
        "role": "annotation"
      }
    ],
    [
      "A",
      0,
      "#64BBF6",
      "0 | R$ 0,00"
    ],
    [
      "B",
      0,
      "#2A8FD7",
      "0 | R$ 0,00"
    ],
    [
      "C",
      0,
      "#0862A2",
      "0 | R$ 0,00"
    ],
    [
      "D",
      0,
      "#64BBF6",
      "0 | R$ 0,00"
    ]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: '',
    chartArea: {
      width: '60%'
    },
    height: 100,
    hAxis: {
      title: '',
      ticks: [0,1,2,3],
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
      },
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: '',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
      },
    },
    legend: {
      position: "none"
    },
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        bold: true
      },
      alwaysOutside: true
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "none"
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```